# using buttons instead of input type="submit" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

I have a form that submits data.

Before I had used the `submit_tag` however, that converts to `<input type="submit"`

I wanted the buttons to look prettier so now I've started using `<button> <span>login</span></button>`

How can I submit the form using `button` the same way it was submitting with `input type=submit` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a JavaScript event handler that obtains a reference to the form and submits it when the `<button>` element is clicked.

Comment: but won't that stop all those validations i've set in my model from appearing? or will they work as is/

Comment: @Mike The validations will still work because you're still submitting the form to the server-side controller action. All that's changed is the client-side code that triggers the form submission.